# Overloading cin >> operator skipping a line of input

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, cin

I have given an abbreviated and generic shot of my code here. I am trying to overload the `>>` operator and do not want my `cin` to terminate on white space.
For some reason it is not taking the first input as the intended for the first attribute. I am not sure how it is determining the cost, it does vary and I suspect may be some ASCII conversion. I am not so worried about that, as if I can get it to accept the first input to be for the first value, I will get a chance to input three times for the three different attributes.

I am sure it is straight forward to an experienced programmer, I am only new to this, thanks.

```
class MyObject  
{    
protected:
    string length;
    string width;
    float cost;

public:
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const MyObject& _myObject);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, MyObject& _myObject);
}

istream& operator>>(istream& input, MyObject& _myObject)
{
    cout << "Enter Length, zones and cost:" << endl;
    std::getline(input, _myObject.length);
    std::getline(input, _myObject.width);
    input >> _myObject.cost;
    return input;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const MyObject& _myObject)
{
    cout.precision(2);
    output << "Length is: " << _myObject.length << "\nWidth is: " << _myObject.width << "\nCost is : $" << fixed << _myObject.cost << endl;
    return output;
}
```

> This Length
>   This Width

goes straight to output:

> Length is:
>   Width is: This Length
>   Cost: $2.50

*Please note in my output, I am using zones not width:*

[image: Output Image]

Comment: [I can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3965b8fc47d579a1). Show the real input file (because for example in your input there's no `2.50`).

Comment: @AntonSavin: From the question, it isn't in his input either: "I am not sure how it is determining the cost, it does vary and I suspect may be some ASCII conversion."

Comment: Note: `cout.precision(2);` should be using `output`, not `cout`, right?

Comment: @user3956566 Try to make [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [here is another demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cdb0485cb9afd706) which takes input from a file. Edit it if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your issue is associated with the prior state of the stream.  If there's a leftover newline character in the buffer, the first `getline` will find it and be finished.

Use `std::getline(input >> ws, _myObject.length);` to discard leading whitespace.

Comment: @user3956566: The `input >> ws` fix is very simple, but it will prevent the input from actually being a blank line (or having leading spaces).  You can instead use `ignore(max, '\n')` after a previous `>>` to leave the buffer empty, and then when this point is reached, you can read an entire line even if it is blank.